# Reorganizng dataframes with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

#### Data

```
exemplo1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(, ncol = 6, nrow = 11))
colnames(exemplo1) <- c(rep("sample1", 6))
rownames(exemplo1) <- c(letters[1:11])

exemplo2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(, ncol = 6, nrow = 11))
colnames(exemplo2) <- c(rep("sample2", 6))
rownames(exemplo2) <- c(letters[1:11])

exemplo3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(, ncol = 6, nrow = 11))
colnames(exemplo3) <- c(rep("sample3", 6))
rownames(exemplo3) <- c(letters[1:11])

exemplo4 <- as.data.frame(matrix(, ncol = 6, nrow = 11))
colnames(exemplo4) <- c(rep("sample4", 6))
rownames(exemplo4) <- c(letters[1:11])

exemplo5 <- as.data.frame(matrix(, ncol = 6, nrow = 11))
colnames(exemplo5) <- c(rep("sample5", 6))
rownames(exemplo5) <- c(letters[1:11])

exemplo6 <- as.data.frame(matrix(, ncol = 6, nrow = 11))
colnames(exemplo6) <- c(rep("sample6", 6))
rownames(exemplo6) <- c(letters[1:11])
```

#### Goal

From this data I want to create 6 other dataframes.

The **first dataframe** (`final1`) should contain be the **first columns** of `exemplo1`, `exemplo2`, `exemplo3`, `exemplo4`, `exemplo5` and `exemplo6`:

```
final1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(, ncol = 6, nrow = 11))
colnames(final1) <- c('sample1','sample2','sample3','sample4','sample5','sample6')
rownames(final1) <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k')
```

The same thing for the second dataframe (`final2`). It should contain the second columns** of `exemplo1`, `exemplo2`, `exemplo3`, `exemplo4`, `exemplo5` and `exemplo6`. And so on...

How can I do this while mantaining the columns names (maybe using `dplyr`)?

Comment: is it necessary for you to have 6 dataframes? Why not combine them into one?

Comment: @JackBrookes yes. Because each dataframe belongs to a specific country in my work.

Comment: are you interested only in `dplyr` solution or are open to base R solutions too ?

Comment: @RonakShah an open base also would be interesting.

Comment: @Laura why can you not have a large dataframe with a column "country" that specifies the country? That would be the normal way of doing it. What if your work adds another country? Are you going to copy and paste the code each time for each country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using base R.

You could add all the dataframes in a list since it is easy to handle lists of dataframes. Now from each lists we extract one by one column, `cbind` them and add it as a dataframe in a list. This assumes that all of your dataframes have same number of columns.

```
lst <- list(exemplo1, exemplo2, exemplo3, exemplo4, exemplo5, exemplo6)
final <- lapply(1:ncol(exemplo1), function(x) Reduce(cbind, lapply(lst, "[", x)))
```

Now, `final[[1]]` is your first dataframe, `final[[2]]` is your second dataframe and so on.